# Are equivalent metrics on a Fréchet space strongly equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $(p_n)_n$ and $(q_n)$ are two increasing sequences of seminorms on a Fréchet space $X$. Each sequence can be used to define a (complete) metric on $X$. For example,

$$d_p(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \min(1,p_n(x-y))$$
and
$$d_q(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \min(1,q_n(x-y))$$

Must these two metrics be strongly equivalent, meaning there exist positive numbers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$a d_p(x,y) \leq d_q(x,y) \leq b d_p(x,y) ?$$

Comment: The question that you can ask is whether a continues linear map between Frechet spaces is necesssarily bounded, here the linear map you would consider is the identity map.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are infinite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ carrying two non-equivalent norms $p$ and $q$ such that both $(V,p)$ and $(V,q)$ are Banach spaces. See 
https://mathoverflow.net/q/184464.

Let $p_n = p, q_n = q$ for all $n$. Then $d_p(x,y) = \min(1,p(x - y)), d_q(x,y) = \min(1,q(x - y))$. These are not strongly equivalent.

Comment: I think the intended question (or the one I infer from the title) is whether two metrics that define Frechet spaces that have the exact same topology (same open sets) are necessarily strongly equivalent? (this is true for normed spaces) Do you have an answer or I should ask it as a separate questions?

Comment: @pitariver You are right, the title does not agree with the text of the question. So you should ask a new question.